# ASP MVC 6 AJAX Bad Request

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My intention is to update a database without completely reloading the current page the user is on when the user submits the data, instead just popping a message box saying success or failure, or something like that.

I have the following JS function which is called when the user clicks a button.

```
function saveListItem(formID)
{
    alert('JS function fired.');
    var _form = $('#mainForm' + formID)
    var _formData = _form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Postings/listItemSubmitted",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { type: "test" },
        success: function () {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error)
        {
            alert(error.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult listItemSubmitted([FromBody] string type)
{
    type += "!!!";
    return Json(type);
}
```

As you can see, I have a few variables that I later intend to use to actually do something. But for now, I'm just trying to get just this TEST to work. The problem is that the action in the controller will not even fire. The error alert gives me "Bad Request."

I've checked the names, all of the names are correct(controller is PostingsController.cs, method name is listItemSubmitted). I've tried every combination of slashes before and after words in the URL syntax. I've even tried using the @Url.Action method, which gave me that string anyway, so I know it's correct.

I don't know what else to try. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: try to give whole url: "http://host/Postings/listItemSubmitted",

Comment: Try removing the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute - you aren't sending the token with your post so this will prevent the request from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem with the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` you've used in you controller as a filter. You have to send the related input value with your data to the server. Try to remove this filter.

Comment: If OP has included `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in the view, then `var _formData = _form.serialize();` will include the token

Comment: @StephenMuecke It will be true if the OP send the serialized form data to the server, but here they didn't do that, so I suggested to remove the filter.

Comment: Yes they have - that is what `var _formData = _form.serialize();` does :)

Comment: The real issue with OP's code is that they should remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` (or else stringify the data) and then the method parameter should be the model that was used in the view and everything will be correctly bound

Comment: @StephenMuecke 'formData' value contains the serialized data, but they didn't send it to server in 'ajax' part.